# New line on kite diagram or margin change?

Tags: r, graph

This is a very basic question I am sure, but I have been trying to fix this for two days and I can't seem to work out how to change the margins so that the label fits in or preferably get the labels to break up onto two lines.

I followed instructions from https://rpubs.com/thoughtfulbloke/kitegraph all using the base graphics options in R- I've passed the relevant part below

```
plot(c(leftedge,rightedge), 
     c(bottomedge,topedge), 
     type= "n", xlab=names(survey)[1], 
     frame.plot=F, yaxt="n", 
      ylab="")
axis(2, 
    labels=names(survey)[2:ncol(survey)], 
    at=1:(ncol(survey)-1), 
    las=2, 
    lty=0)
```

[image of kite diagram label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fg28.png)

Comment: You could add a new line in the labels with `\n`. Did you try that?

Comment: well, I read about that as a solution but I don't quite know how to fit it into the current code and it has not worked for me thus far

Comment: Try `axis(2, 
    labels=gsub(" ", "\n ", names(survey)[2:ncol(survey)]), 
    at=1:(ncol(survey)-1), 
    las=2, 
    lty=0)`

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you so much! I can't tell you how much time you have saved me. I am now gonna do more reading to try understand how to figure the solution on my own. Thanks so much again

Comment: You're welcome! I turned my comment into an answer. You can upvote & accept it to indicate that the question is settled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, the following axis modification worked to solve the problem,

```
axis(2, 
    labels=gsub(" ", "\n ", 
    names(survey)[2:ncol(survey)]), 
    at=1:(ncol(survey)-1), las=2, lty=0)
```